# The person version of second country

Tags: single-word-requests

The person version of second country

Like average looking, average money, average car, average house...

Not best of me. Not just about money

Sum of living in the middle

How to call this?

Edit: It's like I am in a middle class without class concept. More vague.

Comment: I have no idea what you're getting at. Please explain more clearly.

Comment: Do you mean someone who is like a fish out of water?

Answer (score 1):

Such a person is an 'average Joe' or 'average Jane' (depending on their gender - I'm not aware of an equivalent expression for non-binary persons).

> The terms **average Joe, ordinary Joe, Joe Sixpack, Joe Lunchbucket, Joe Snuffy, [Joe Schmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Shmoe)** (for males) and **ordinary Jane, average Jane,** and **plain Jane** (for females), are used primarily in North America to refer to a completely average person, typically an average American. It can be used both to give the image of a hypothetical "completely average person" or to describe an existing person. [Parallel terms in other languages for local equivalents exist worldwide.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terms_related_to_an_average_person)

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_Joe))

Answer (score 0):

[Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tom-dick-and-harry):

> **Tom, Dick, and/or Harry**:  *an ordinary, undistinguished, or common person*

e.g. We don't want our daughter marring any Tom, Dick, or Harry (meaning an average person but in a disapproving way. They'd rather see their daughter marry someone distinguished)